# How to join similar elements of array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, performance, recursion

We are running a PHP code on a huge list (array with 5 millions elements).

The list format is as follows below (it looks "weird" at first look but this is the best format so far we came out in order to optimize the speed of the code down below)

```
$array = array(

    array(1 => true,3 => true),
    array(2 => true,4 => true,6 => true),
    array(3 => true,5 => true),
    array(5 => true),
    array(4 => true,8 => true,10 => true),
    array(200 => true,300 => true)

);
```

We want to combine similar elements from the array above and get to this result:

```
$final_array = array(

    array(1,3,5),
    array(2,4,6,8,10),
    array(200,300)

);
```

Instead of using `array(1,3)` we decided to use `array(1 => true,3 => true)` because using keys instead of values (to store information) makes the code below runs faster and it outputs `$final_array` as above.

```
foreach ($array as $key1 => $value1) {

    foreach ($array as $key2 => $value2) {

        if ($key1 != $key2) {

            foreach ($array[$key1] as $key3 => $value3) {

                if (isset($array[$key2][$key3])) {

                    $array[$key2] = $array[$key2] + $array[$key1];

                    unset($array[$key1]);

                    break 2;

                }

            }   

        }

    }

}
```

However this code above is still very slow. Could you find a better way to aggregate similar elements to each other on a faster code?

Comment: What you want to achieve?

Comment: @YasinPatel We want to join similar elements of the array, that are separated, to be together. For example: if there is one element containing 1,2 and another element containing 2,4 we want to join it all and get 1,2,4 together in a final array.

Comment: It is really really not clear why 1,3,5 are similiar but 2,4,6,8,10 are NOT similiar. but they are similair to each other. By similiar do you mean Odd and Even?

Comment: Or do you mean you want to get rid of the duplicates?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Let me clarify: if an element has 1,2 and another has 2,4 then there is a "link" between those two elements which is the number 2. If 1 and 2 are together and if 2 and 4 are together, then 1 and 4 must be together with 2. I cant find a better way to say this in english sorry.

Comment: So what you actually need is optimisation? , ie the code should run with limited time  since the input array value is in millions.

Comment: Ok thats clearer, but  with 5,000,000 elements this could take some serious time to run if each occurance has to be checked with all other occurances

Comment: I am quite impressed that you managed to create an array with 5million occurances in the first place. Wouldn't it be better to optimize the process that BUILDS this array rather then re-process the whole array again once created

Comment: @RiggsFolly the input of my code above is the output from a very complex AI multilayered algorithm and the company I work for has to manipulate the output of the AI algoritm to do some work. I've seen the output with even 20 million elements, but it freezes completely our dedicated servers (runs low on RAM) and we are processing it in groups of 5 millions each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [array_intersect_key](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) instead of third loop?

```
$array = array(
    array(1 => true,3 => true),
    array(2 => true,4 => true,6 => true),
    array(3 => true,5 => true),
    array(5 => true),
    array(4 => true,8 => true,10 => true),
    array(200 => true,300 => true)

);
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($array as $key2 => $value2) {
        if ($key !== $key2 && !empty(array_intersect_key($value, $value2))) {
            $array[$key] = $value2 + $value;
            unset($array[$key2]);
        }
    }
}

print_r($array);
```

[Working example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a4292d9f7533c1dfeae68d44b83b466fc7a744fa)

**Edit #1:**
For better performance try this variant:

```
$array = array(
    array(1 => true,3 => true),
    array(2 => true,4 => true,6 => true),
    array(3 => true,5 => true),
    array(5 => true),
    array(4 => true,8 => true,10 => true),
    array(200 => true,300 => true)

);
$count = count($array);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count - 1; ++$i) {
    for ($j = $i + 1; $j < $count; ++$j) {
        if (!empty(array_intersect_key($array[$i], $array[$j]))) {
            $array[$j] = $array[$i] + $array[$j];
            unset($array[$i]);
            continue 2;
        }
    }
}
```

[Working example #2](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7f0c184fd0cf82900777c1e363ce28f8c7a781bc)

Comment: Your code is much more beautiful than ours and clearer to read! \o/ However it runs slower. The reason is that `array_intersect_key` wont stop untill all the elements of the parameter's array are checked. On the other hand, the code that I posted at the top `breaks` when a single match is found. I am sad, I really thought your code would be faster!

Comment: @Samul check please updated answer, I guess it has better performance

Comment: It improved but not by a lot (I tested 1m iterations) using `for` instead `forach`. I tried replacing `if (!empty(array_intersect_key($array[$i], $array[$j]))) {` with `if (!array_intersect_key($array[$i], $array[$j])) {` and worked a lit bit better but still not better than my original code. What amazes me is that `array_intersect_key` was not much slower, if there was a way to make it "stop" processing when find an intersect, surely it would be better than the original code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array('Hello','World!','Beautiful','Day!');
echo join(" ",$arr);
```

[See Details](https://www.w3schools.com/php/phptryit.asp?filename=tryphp_func_string_join2)

Comment: kkkk worth a try! However this day is not going well so far here, we are 2 months delayed in this project and we are stuck with performance optimizations on backend

Comment: Then try with  array_merge() function.